# is there a firefox addon that provides jsFiddle like features

Tags: layout, firefox-addon, jsfiddle

I just saw jsFiddle today and am wondering that is there a FireFox addon that provides jsFiddle like features. Especially when you enter the html and css, jsFiddle shows you a layout of the page. Is there any addon that shows such layout for "offline viewing"? I use Firebug but there isn't such layout. Does somebody know about it?

Answer (score 1):

Not a firefox add-on, only in the interest of self-promotion:

I have created a Vim script with similar (but at the moment very limited) functionality: [vimfiddler](https://github.com/codeape2/vimfiddler). Vim integrates with selenium to drive a browser. Provides a jsfiddlerish experience running locally on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome you can edit every element of the page. Just open a new tab, hit `F-12` and edit to your heart's desire. Add some css or javascript to the `head` tags, put whatever HTML you want in the `body`, and you're good to go.

Comment: that i can do with firebug also. i want to see layout like jsFiddle shows. it gives a very clear idea of the structure of page

Comment: well without finding/creating a plugin, you could open three files in an editor like vim or notepad++, create an HTML file, a CSS file, and a javascript file, then open the html in Firefox. Of course it's not as clean and you'd have to reference the files yourself, but it get's the job done for times when you don't have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

This add-on sounds like what you need : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/devtools-prototyper/?src=ss

Just install it, open the devtools, then switch to the "Prototyper" tab.